# Node require not finding my file

Tags: javascript, node.js

So i have this directory structure

```
--- root
  |--- server
     |--- config
        |--- pfio
           |--- pfio-server.js
           |--- event-bus.js
  |--- server.js
```

In my `pfio-server.js` file i require the `event-bus.js` file so I use this:

```
var eventBus = require('./server/config/pfio/event-bus');
```

This is pretty standard, goes without saying really. However, when I run the `server.js` it says it can't find the module `event-bus`

Say what....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Node, imports are relatives from the current file (if you do a relative import) so if you're in `pfio-server.js` you can simply `require('./event-bus');`

Comment: I always imagined `./` as the current working directory for Node, and not neccessarely the current file, but I could be wrong as process.cwd() is really the working directory?

Comment: I have a project where I have `whatever/core/, whatever/common/, whatever/startup.js`, I require a `core` file from `startup.js` with `require './core/whatever'` and a file in `common` from a file in `core` with `require '../common/whatever'`. It works well since ever.

Comment: As noted, I wasn't really sure, but I looked at some of my own node plugins and routes that I've written etc. and I've always instinctively used `process.cwd()` when I have to reference something from the root level, and just the filename when the require is in the same directory or `node_modules`, so I've never had this issue, and I've never tried to see what `./` really does, as I've never needed to, so you're probably right?

Comment: Just quickly tested, made a project with a `start.js` file only doing `require './foo/bar'`. In `foo/bar.js` I require `fs` and relatively mkdir a `./testdir`. The dir is created under `foo` ;)

Comment: Also @adeneo, I'm quite skeptical about this behavior too.